# Laravel groupBy sometimes returns object and for some other data it returns array of array

Tags: laravel, eloquent

my code works perfect for some data and for other it returns object data type where it should return array of arrays..

Here is my code and queries

```
 $matches = $this->query->getFixtureandresult($id);
 return $matches->groupBy('round');
```

And my query is

```
public function getFixtureandresult($id){
    return Fixtureandresult::where('division_id', $id)
            ->with(['date', 'home.player1', 'home.player2', 'away.player1', 'away.player2', 'court'])->orderBy('playingTime','asc')
            ->get();
}
```

For one `division_id`, I get bellow types of data , bellow is the incorrect data formate it returns

[image]

It should return data like this image
[image]

Not sure, why I get two data types returned.

Anyone knows the reason please put your valuable input. Thank you.

Comment: Use `toArray()` method, `…->get()->toArray();` on your collection

Comment: Why not perform the `->groupBy('round')` on the query instead on the collection?